Search phrase in Google sheets and return cell number using Make.com
I have raw data in a spreadsheet with headers. In & after column F, my headers are “Lesson Name” and “Completed Date”, and these repeat until column Z.
In row two, I have my data. For column F, the lesson name is “Welcome!”, column G is empty (under Completed Date), column H is “Course Overview”, column I is empty, etc. I basically need a way to search the sheet using Make.com modules for “Course Overview” and return either the column that it is in, ie “H2” or more ideally the column next to it, ie, “I2”. How can I do this?? I have tried using the “Search Rows” module but this only lets me search 1 specific column at a time. I have not had any luck using Queries either, but my knowledge of queries is limited. The goal here is to find a value via a variable (such as "Course Overview") and input a timestamp into the cell next to it. Any help you can provide would be amazing.
Edit: Here is a screenshot of my data:

I just need a way to search for a user by email, which I am using the "Search Rows" module for successfully, but then to search THAT row (in this case, Row 2) for a lesson title and return the cell/column it is in (or the one next to it, I'd take either at this point.)

Can you provide a minimum reproducible sample? Highlighting the format and structure of your data, along with your expected result?

Sure, sorry, I updated my post

Thank you for replying. so just to make sure you are trying to get an answer from a make.com perspective and not a Google sheet formula perspective is this correct?

Yes that is correct, it must be done in Make.com
